# iid random variables visualization

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, pointwise-convergence

I am thinking $X_1, X_2, \cdots$ being iid random variables, that map $\omega \in \{0,1\}$ to $\{0,1\}$. If $\omega = 0$, then $X_i = 0$; if $\omega = 1$, then $X_i = 1$.

However, if we define this way, all the $X_i$'s are the same. Where is the randomness coming from? In this stage, we have not yet define any probability measure. How should we visualize iid random variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use this definition for all $X_i$, then they are *not* independent because they will all have the same value. When you fix a single $\omega$, you automatically fix values (realizations) for every random variable in the universe. In your definition, choosing either value of $\omega$ fixes $X_1\left(\omega\right)=X_2\left(\omega\right)=...$ to be the same value.

When one works with random variables, one rarely defines them on the outcome space directly, nor does one attempt to precisely define what the outcome space is. Rather, one assumes that there exists some outcome space, but one works only with the probability measure induced by various distributions. So, when you say that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent Bernoulli random variables, you are implicitly assuming the existence of some suitable probability space $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P\right)$, but it is not necessary to explicitly define all of these for virtually anything that you might want to do with the random variables. It is sufficient to know $P\left(A\right)$ for events $A$ involving the random variables.

However, if you really wanted to define an outcome space for two independent $Bernoulli\left(p\right)$ random variables, you would need four outcomes with

\begin{eqnarray*}
X_1\left(\omega_1\right) &=& 1, X_2\left(\omega_1\right) = 1\\
X_1\left(\omega_2\right) &=& 1, X_2\left(\omega_2\right) = 0\\
X_1\left(\omega_3\right) &=& 0, X_2\left(\omega_3\right) = 1\\
X_1\left(\omega_4\right) &=& 0, X_2\left(\omega_4\right) = 0\\
\end{eqnarray*}

with $P\left(\left\{\omega_1\right\}\right) = p^2$, $P\left(\left\{\omega_2\right\}\right) = P\left(\left\{\omega_3\right\}\right) = p\left(1-p\right)$, and $P\left(\left\{\omega_4\right\}\right) = \left(1-p\right)^2$.

Comment: Alternatively, we can simply take the outcome space to be $\mathcal{Z}=\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\},$ and take $(X_1,X_2)$ to be the *identity map* on $\mathcal{Z};$ i.e., $(X_1,X_2):\mathcal{Z}\to\mathcal{Z}:(z_1,z_2)\mapsto(z_1,z_2).$ (Intuitively, $(X_1,X_2)$ simply "names" a "random element" of $\mathcal{Z}.$

Comment: @sven  thank you, but if we want to talk about convergence, say $X_i$ does not converge a.s., what sample space should we work on? Should we consider samples space being ${0,1}^n$ for $X_n$? But then $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ do not have the same sample space.

Comment: All random variables must always be defined on the sample space. The space $\left\{0,1\right\}^n$ is the _range_ of the vector-valued function $\left(X_1,...,X_n\right)$. The _domain_ is still the same $\Omega$. When you study convergence, you typically assume that there is an underlying probability space, but you very rarely have to actually _construct_ $\Omega$ unless you are designing some abstruse counterexample. If you are just studying a.s. convergence, virtually always you just fix an $\omega$ and study the deterministic sequence $\left\{X_n\left(\omega\right)\right\}$.

Comment: @svensvenson okay, so can we think $X_n(\omega)$ as a projection of the first $n$ coordinate of $\omega$, where $\omega$ is an infinite sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s?

Comment: If $X_n\left(\omega\right)$ is the $n$th random variable, I think it should just be the $n$th coordinate of $\omega = \left(\omega_1,\omega_2,...\right)$. Then $\Omega$ is uncountable, so $P$ has to be defined on subsets of it.

Comment: The answer is correct, but I would write e.g. $P(\{\omega\})$ instead of $P(\omega_i)$ to make it more clear that $P$ is defined for subsets of, rather than elements of, the sample space.

Comment: Yes, good point. Edited.